# UWP BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync() returns null

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a customer's laptop that will not connect to a bluetooth printer. It's a classic, works on my machine (and several others) situation. I have a feeling that it's a security permission, anti virus, etc I'm just trying to prove it or find the security setting to get it to work or rewrite my code to handle this situation. -- you know solve the problem.

The printer does pair with the laptop without any issues (prints a pairing key), but when I try to find it from Id it always returns a null:

```
var bluetoothDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id) //bluetoothDevice = null
```

I tried both [BluetoothDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice?view=winrt-18362) and [BluetoothLeDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice?view=winrt-18362) API's, no luck.

I used Microsoft's sample [GATT services](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) and I get the same results. Failed to connect to device on the laptop, works fine on my dev machine.

I added the DeviceAccessInformation API to get the current status and it returns:

```
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedByUser 
//on my dev machine I get DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed
```

I cannot find anything on DeviceAccessInformation API that tells me why/how it's returning DeniedByUser.

As always, Thanks for taking the time.

Windows Version: 1909 (18363.78)

Applicable code:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector());

foreach (var device in devices)
{

    var accessStatus = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(device.Id).CurrentStatus;

    textLog.AppendLine($"---DeviceId: {device.Id} -- {accessStatus}");

    using (var bluetoothDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id))
    {
        if (bluetoothDevice == null)
        {
            textLog.AppendLine($"---DeviceId: {device.Id} Not Found");
            textLog.AppendLine($"---Device Information: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(device)}");
            txtLog.Text = textLog.ToString();
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Remote Laptop Log output:

```
connecting to ac:3f:a4:dd:69:a7
---DeviceId: Bluetooth#Bluetoothac:67:5d:1d:d5:25-ac:3f:a4:dd:69:a7 -- DeniedByUser
---DeviceId: Bluetooth#Bluetoothac:67:5d:1d:d5:25-ac:3f:a4:dd:69:a7 Not Found
---Device Information: {"EnclosureLocation":null,"Id":"Bluetooth#Bluetoothac:67:5d:1d:d5:25-ac:3f:a4:dd:69:a7","IsDefault":false,"IsEnabled":false,"Name":"dev-zebra1","Properties":{},"Kind":5,"Pairing":{"CanPair":false,"IsPaired":false,"Custom":{},"ProtectionLevel":1}}
---Printer [ac:3f:a4:dd:69:a7] not found
```

My Dev Machine Log output:

```
connecting to ac:3f:a4:dd:69:a7
---DeviceId: Bluetooth#Bluetooth00:23:15:d4:a2:e1-ac:3f:a4:dd:69:a7 -- Allowed
---Device Information: {"EnclosureLocation":null,"Id":"Bluetooth#Bluetooth00:23:15:d4:a2:e1-ac:3f:a4:dd:69:a7","IsDefault":false,"IsEnabled":false,"Name":"dev-zebra1","Properties":{},"Kind":5,"Pairing":{"CanPair":false,"IsPaired":false,"Custom":{},"ProtectionLevel":1}}
```

--- UPDATE ---

I already had the capabilities set according to the link provided by David. I tired putting all Function types in there but nothing changed on the laptop. I added the webcam capability and I saw the toggle show up under app permissions. But I never see a bluetooth toggle.

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
    <Device Id="any">
       <Function Type ="name:serialPort"/>
    </Device>
   </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

Start Menu -> Settings -> Privacy Settings: 
[image: privacySettings]
Other Devices and toggle the device: 
[image]

I was able to enable the toggle by going into the registry and setting **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppPrivacy\LetAppsAccessTrustedDevices** DWORD to 0. Rebooted the machine, checked privacy settings to enable the device and the printer started to work.

[More Info on the GPO / Registry settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/privacy/manage-connections-from-windows-operating-system-components-to-microsoft-services#bkmk-priv-other-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the option for the Bluetooth Capability in the Package.appxmanifest?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-bluetooth

Enabling this capability in the manifest should resolve the problem. Note, the user still has the option to disallow access for the app in settings, but if the capability is selected and the user gives the app permission to access Bluetooth, this should resolve.

Otherwise, What OS versions are used by the working/failing machines? And, by chance, did you try disabling the firewall temporarily to test this? Is there a UAC prompt when connecting? Have you tried this as admin on the failing machine, just as a test?

Comment: I just have the bluetooth capability checked on the Capabilities Tab in the app manifest. I'll look at customizing it tonight.

- OS Version is the same: 1909 build 18363.778 

- Pretty sure I tested it with firewall disabled - I'll double check

- No UAC prompt on the laptop or my dev machine

- I am running as a local Admin on the laptop, I believe I tried running the test app as administrator as well, but I'll run that test again.

Comment: I cannot turn off the firewall on the laptop because it's controlled by group policies.